# Validating API input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Various parameters are appended to the API URL.

There is data that needs to be validated by ruby (as rails does not process validations before creating/modifying data) before processing.
The following returns true with a given string, but the parametrized version always returns true

```
!1e48.is_a? Integer

(!params[:id].is_a? Integer)
```

I realise rails considers all paramters as strings, but converting the params `to_i` or some other type leads onto a garden path. What would be appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more restrictive [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) function:

```
!(Integer(params[:id]) rescue nil)
```

Comment: Very useful reference. Reading through it, I noticed it has no function to handle date.  Is there a reason for this (or other function to validate such input)?